# Flutter, type 'int' is not a subtype of 'string' calling rest api

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter & dart but have a had a blast learning about them, currently I am stuck on trying to fetch data inside the app I have followed the docs [Flutter Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) created the model file and the Future to call the api all code is bellow. I have done some research and tried a couple of things but nothing has solved the error `type 'int' is not a subtype of 'string'` this is most likely a simple error but any pointers is appreciated.

Apologies if any info is missed I had to type this in a hurry. Let me know if anything else is required!

API Used: https://valorant-api.com/v1/currencies

```json
API Response
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "uuid": "85ad13f7-3d1b-5128-9eb2-7cd8ee0b5741",
            "displayName": "VP",
            "displayNameSingular": "VP",
            "displayIcon": "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/85ad13f7-3d1b-5128-9eb2-7cd8ee0b5741/displayicon.png",
            "largeIcon": "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/85ad13f7-3d1b-5128-9eb2-7cd8ee0b5741/largeicon.png",
            "assetPath": "ShooterGame/Content/Currencies/Currency_AresPoints_DataAsset"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "85ca954a-41f2-ce94-9b45-8ca3dd39a00d",
            "displayName": "Dough",
            "displayNameSingular": "Dough",
            "displayIcon": "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/85ca954a-41f2-ce94-9b45-8ca3dd39a00d/displayicon.png",
            "largeIcon": "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/85ca954a-41f2-ce94-9b45-8ca3dd39a00d/largeicon.png",
            "assetPath": "ShooterGame/Content/Currencies/Currency_Dough_DataAsset"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "f08d4ae3-939c-4576-ab26-09ce1f23bb37",
            "displayName": "Free Agents",
            "displayNameSingular": "Free Agent",
            "displayIcon": "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/f08d4ae3-939c-4576-ab26-09ce1f23bb37/displayicon.png",
            "largeIcon": "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/f08d4ae3-939c-4576-ab26-09ce1f23bb37/largeicon.png",
            "assetPath": "ShooterGame/Content/Currencies/Currency_RecruitmentToken_DataAsset"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "e59aa87c-4cbf-517a-5983-6e81511be9b7",
            "displayName": "Radianite Points",
            "displayNameSingular": "Radianite Point",
            "displayIcon": "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/e59aa87c-4cbf-517a-5983-6e81511be9b7/displayicon.png",
            "largeIcon": "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/e59aa87c-4cbf-517a-5983-6e81511be9b7/largeicon.png",
            "assetPath": "ShooterGame/Content/Currencies/Currency_UpgradeToken_DataAsset"
        }
    ]
}
```

```dart
Model file
class CurrencyModel {
  final String status;
  final int uuid;
  final String displayName;
  final String displayNameSingular;
  final String displayIcon;
  final String largeIcon;
  final String assetPath;

  const CurrencyModel({
    required this.status,
    required this.uuid,
    required this.assetPath,
    required this.displayIcon,
    required this.displayName,
    required this.displayNameSingular,
    required this.largeIcon,
  });

  factory CurrencyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CurrencyModel(
      status: json['status'],
      uuid: int.parse(json['data']['uuid']),
      assetPath: json['data']['assestPath'], 
      displayIcon: json['data']['displayIcon'], 
      displayName: json['data']['displayName'], 
      displayNameSingular: json['data']['displayNameSingular'], 
      largeIcon: json['data']['largeIcon'],
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
Data Fetch file
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:valoranttools/models/models.dart';

Future<CurrencyModel> fetchCurrency() async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('https://valorant-api.com/v1/currencies'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    print(response.body);
    return CurrencyModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final currencyModel = currencyModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

CurrencyModel currencyModelFromJson(String str) => CurrencyModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String currencyModelToJson(CurrencyModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CurrencyModel {
    int status;
    List<Datum> data;

    CurrencyModel({
        required this.status,
        required this.data,
    });

    factory CurrencyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CurrencyModel(
        status: json["status"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    String uuid;
    String displayName;
    String displayNameSingular;
    String displayIcon;
    String largeIcon;
    String assetPath;

    Datum({
        required this.uuid,
        required this.displayName,
        required this.displayNameSingular,
        required this.displayIcon,
        required this.largeIcon,
        required this.assetPath,
    });

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        uuid: json["uuid"],
        displayName: json["displayName"],
        displayNameSingular: json["displayNameSingular"],
        displayIcon: json["displayIcon"],
        largeIcon: json["largeIcon"],
        assetPath: json["assetPath"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "uuid": uuid,
        "displayName": displayName,
        "displayNameSingular": displayNameSingular,
        "displayIcon": displayIcon,
        "largeIcon": largeIcon,
        "assetPath": assetPath,
    };
}
```

Comment: This was the best solution and definitely the quickest but both were an awesome learning point and I'm sure I'll have more questions in the future, all I ask is next time possibly include a little more info with the response, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `Currencymodel` you are trying to add a string to int

change this line `final int uuid;` to this `final String uuid;`

as @OMi Shah mentioned you need to remove `int.parse` and use it like this `uuid: json['data']['uuid'],`

if you have a problem with your status, then you need to parse it to int like this `int.parse(json['status']),`

Comment: just changing the type wont fix, because of this: ``int.parse(json['data']['uuid']),`` so you have to remove the parsing i.e ``uuid: json['data']['uuid'], ...``

Comment: yes , that's correct (I didn't see that)

Comment: Huge thanks for the quick answers, I tried this and unfortunately it just results in the error I had before, `type 'int' is not a Subtype of type 'String'` does it have anything to do with the fact that in the response `status` is a `int`?

Comment: check now I updated My answer

Comment: Thanks, will do very shortly Ill let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

- Create proper model class from json and try
- https://itsallwidgets.com/json-to-dart-converter-support-null-safety

ex:

```
class CurrencyModel {
  final int? status;
  final List<Data>? data;

  CurrencyModel({
    this.status,
    this.data,
  });

  CurrencyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : status = json['status'] as int?,
      data = (json['data'] as List?)?.map((dynamic e) => Data.fromJson(e as Map<String,dynamic>)).toList();

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'status' : status,
    'data' : data?.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList()
  };
}

class Data {
  final String? uuid;
  final String? displayName;
  final String? displayNameSingular;
  final String? displayIcon;
  final String? largeIcon;
  final String? assetPath;

  Data({
    this.uuid,
    this.displayName,
    this.displayNameSingular,
    this.displayIcon,
    this.largeIcon,
    this.assetPath,
  });

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : uuid = json['uuid'] as String?,
      displayName = json['displayName'] as String?,
      displayNameSingular = json['displayNameSingular'] as String?,
      displayIcon = json['displayIcon'] as String?,
      largeIcon = json['largeIcon'] as String?,
      assetPath = json['assetPath'] as String?;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'uuid' : uuid,
    'displayName' : displayName,
    'displayNameSingular' : displayNameSingular,
    'displayIcon' : displayIcon,
    'largeIcon' : largeIcon,
    'assetPath' : assetPath
  };
}

// your code

Map<String, dynamic> json = {
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
      {
        "uuid": "85ad13f7-3d1b-5128-9eb2-7cd8ee0b5741",
        "displayName": "VP",
        "displayNameSingular": "VP",
        "displayIcon":
            "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/85ad13f7-3d1b-5128-9eb2-7cd8ee0b5741/displayicon.png",
        "largeIcon":
            "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/85ad13f7-3d1b-5128-9eb2-7cd8ee0b5741/largeicon.png",
        "assetPath":
            "ShooterGame/Content/Currencies/Currency_AresPoints_DataAsset"
      },
      {
        "uuid": "85ca954a-41f2-ce94-9b45-8ca3dd39a00d",
        "displayName": "Dough",
        "displayNameSingular": "Dough",
        "displayIcon":
            "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/85ca954a-41f2-ce94-9b45-8ca3dd39a00d/displayicon.png",
        "largeIcon":
            "https://media.valorant-api.com/currencies/85ca954a-41f2-ce94-9b45-8ca3dd39a00d/largeicon.png",
        "assetPath": "ShooterGame/Content/Currencies/Currency_Dough_DataAsset"
      }
    ]
  };
    
 CurrencyModel cModel = CurrencyModel.fromJson(
      json); // responseJson (json) - Map<String, dynamic>

  print(cModel.data!.length);


`
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I attempted this method with a seperate `Data` class with the other types in it and this results in a different error after mapping through `type list<dynamic> is not a subtype of list<data>?`

Answer (score 0):

Change
`final int uuid;` to `final String uuid;`
in the model class

---

Change
`uuid: int.parse(json['data']['uuid'])`, to `uuid: json['data']['uuid']`

Answer (score 0):

**because you are trying to parse the "uuid" field from the API response as an int**

```
class CurrencyModel {
      final int status;
      final String uuid;
      final String displayName;
      final String displayNameSingular;
      final String displayIcon;
      final String largeIcon;
      final String assetPath;
    
      const CurrencyModel({
        required this.status,
        required this.uuid,
        required this.assetPath,
        required this.displayIcon,
        required this.displayName,
        required this.displayNameSingular,
        required this.largeIcon,
      });
    
      factory CurrencyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return CurrencyModel(
          status: json['status'],
          uuid: json['data']['uuid'],
          assetPath: json['data']['assetPath'], 
          displayIcon: json['data']['displayIcon'], 
          displayName: json['data']['displayName'], 
          displayNameSingular: json['data']['displayNameSingular'], 
          largeIcon: json['data']['largeIcon'],
        );
      }
    }
```